# control reaches end of non-void function. How to solve this?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

solution.c: In function ‘subtractProductAndSum’
Line 31: Char 1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] [solution.c]
}
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

```
int subtractProductAndSum(int n){

    int k , j=n , count=0 , add=0 , multiply=1;
  
    while(j>0){
    
        j=j/10;
        count++;
    
    }

    int p=count;
    int arr[p];
        
    while(n>0){
        k=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        
        if(p>0){        
            arr[p-1]=k;
            p--;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <count ;i++){
      add=add+arr[i];
      multiply=multiply*arr[i];
    }
    
    int t=multiply-add;
    printf("%d", t);
    
}
```

Comment: Is this function supposed to print the result? Return the result? Or both? You ask us how to fix it but don't tell us what the desired result is. There are no comments, so we cannot tell what the desired behavior of the function is.

Comment: Well, you said you'd return an `int` and you're not. Either you should, and you'll need to figure out what the output of this function should be, or it should have a `void` return type.

Comment: so I found the question on Leetcode.
Given an integer number n, return the difference between the product of its digits and the sum of its digits.

 
@DavidSchwartz

Comment: nevermind it is solved , thanks. @RetiredNinja

Comment: @Rushil, "return" involves executing a `return` statement.  That's an altogether different thing from *printing* or otherwise writing to a file.

Comment: This algorithm will give the wrong answer (1) if parameter n == 0. That may need attention... Also, you store individual values (0-9). When you multiply one of those that happens to be 0, the multiply accumulator will never change from 0 afterward... The problem statement might be "multiply all non-zero digits together"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 leetcode accepted the answer so I don't know.

Comment: @Rushil `int add=0,mul=1;while(n)add+=n%10,mul*=n%10,n/=10;return mul-add;` Here's the whole function body, suitable for copy/paste between the curly braces. You'll want to print the return value of the function in the calling function.

Comment: @Rushil And, how does it handle negative numbers??

Comment: @Fe2O3 wasn't in the test case , I guess the numbers were non negative number >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is declared as an int, meaning it's expected to return an int. Your function doesn't return an int -- in fact, it doesn't return anything.

As @Retired Ninja said, you need to figure out what you want your function to return, and add an appropriate return statement.

Comment: no worries , it is solved.
I was just printing the answer that needed to be solved.

Comment: I'm glad you got your code working to your satisfaction. As John Bollinger said, though, the solution to your problem as stated in your title is one of two options: 1) make the function void, or 2) return a value consistent with the function type.